# Dell studio 1535 does not boot on pressing Power Button

Tags: dell-studio

I have a dell stdio 1535 model. When I press the power button, it produces 6 Beep sound and doesn't boot up. Please suggest some way to overcome it.

Comment: [Beep codes](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/w/desktop/3624.beep-codes-and-psa-diagnostic-chart.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

According to the chart on [Dell's website](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/w/desktop/3624.beep-codes-and-psa-diagnostic-chart.aspx), 6 beeps means there is a Video BIOS Test Failure, meaning the Video card / chip has tested bad.

This is not something you're likely to fix without replacing some hardware inside that laptop.